# How to use @State with Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, swiftui

I would like to be able to pass a Dictionary value to a view but it doesn't seem possible. The following generates a number of errors. Is there a way to do this?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{
    @State var dict:[String:String] = ["Key":"Value"]
    var body: some View
    {
        TextEditor(text: $dict["Key]"])
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider
{
    static var previews: some View
    {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Some double quotes mistake  : $dict["Key"]

Comment: Thanks for that, but that wasn't the problem. Still generates errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution I found on the [swift forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/swiftui-how-to-use-dictionary-as-binding/34967/2) by Rob Mayoff that I think should work here to.

Create a function that creates a non-optional binding to the value in the dictionary for a given key and that updates the dictionary when the binding is updated

```
private func binding(for key: String) -> Binding<String> {
    return .init(
        get: { self.dict[key, default: ""] },
        set: { self.dict[key] = $0 })
}
```

And call it when creating the view

```
TextEditor(text: binding(for: "Key"))
```